# Pandas: sum first N elements under certain condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
date                      condition        count        Value 
01,01,2018 08:00             A               1            0
01,01,2018 08:01             A               2            1
01,01,2018 08:02             A               3            4
01,01,2018 08:03             B               1            2
01,01,2018 08:04             B               2            1
01,01,2018 08:05             B               3            7
01,01,2018 08:06             B               4            0
01,01,2018 08:07             C               1            11
01,01,2018 08:08             C               2            2
01,01,2018 08:09             C               3            0
01,01,2018 08:10             C               4            0
01,01,2018 08:11             C               5            0
01,01,2018 08:12             A               1            3
01,01,2018 08:13             A               2            1
01,01,2018 08:14             B               1            0
01,01,2018 08:15             B               2            0
01,01,2018 08:16             B               3            0
01,01,2018 08:17             C               1            8
```

I am trying to check if the sum of the values are = 0, under specific conditions:

The sum has to be carried out within the interval from count=1 to count=3, if condition=B.
Then, if the sum of values of such interval = 0, another column called error should give value 1.

In this example, sum=10 from 08:03 to 08:05; and sum=0 from 08:14 to 08:16. So, in this case the values in the column error should be all =0, apart from 08:14 to 08:16, where they should be =1.

Obtaining:

```
  date                      condition        count        Value     error
    01,01,2018 08:00             A               1            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:01             A               2            1         0
    01,01,2018 08:02             A               3            4         0
    01,01,2018 08:03             B               1            2         0
    01,01,2018 08:04             B               2            1         0
    01,01,2018 08:05             B               3            7         0
    01,01,2018 08:06             B               4            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:07             C               1            11        0
    01,01,2018 08:08             C               2            2         0
    01,01,2018 08:09             C               3            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:10             C               4            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:11             C               5            0         0
    01,01,2018 08:12             A               1            3         0
    01,01,2018 08:13             A               2            1         0
    01,01,2018 08:14             B               1            0         1
    01,01,2018 08:15             B               2            0         1
    01,01,2018 08:16             B               3            0         1
    01,01,2018 08:17             C               1            8         0
```

I have tried with

```
df['error']=np.where((df['condition']==B) & (df['count']<=5) & (df['value'].sum==0), 1, 0)
```

or if/for cycles, but I get errors.

It doesn't really matter to have 1 on each error value in the interval, or just in one row in the interval, it is enough that 1 appears somewhere there, so that I can recognize it. Maybe, the interval could be selected looking at the first 3 minutes when condition B starts, rather than the count (the count just sounds easier to me).

Any idea? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: can you also post the file for the data?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, it is confidential. I have created this to provide an example.

Comment: I've copied-pasted my dataframe and manually changed the values for the example, there is no code creating the dataframe, it comes from an imported excel file with times and values.

Comment: @sobek data as text is generally sufficient - use `StringIO` and `pd.read_csv` with `sep='\s+'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
df['rolling'] = df['Value'].rolling(3).sum()

df['error'] = np.where((df['condition'] == 'B') & (df['count'].ge(3)),
                        df['rolling'].eq(0), np.nan)
df['error'] = np.where(df['condition'] == 'B',
                       df['error'].bfill(), 0)
```

This gives you:

```
             date condition  count  Value  rolling  error
01,01,2018  08:00         A      1      0      NaN    0.0
01,01,2018  08:01         A      2      1      NaN    0.0
01,01,2018  08:02         A      3      4      5.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:03         B      1      2      7.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:04         B      2      1      7.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:05         B      3      7     10.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:06         B      4      0      8.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:07         C      1     11     18.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:08         C      2      2     13.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:09         C      3      0     13.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:10         C      4      0      2.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:11         C      5      0      0.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:12         A      1      3      3.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:13         A      2      1      4.0    0.0
01,01,2018  08:14         B      1      0      4.0    1.0
01,01,2018  08:15         B      2      0      1.0    1.0
01,01,2018  08:16         B      3      0      0.0    1.0
01,01,2018  08:17         C      1      8      8.0    0.0
```

If you don't want the `'rolling'` column we can condense it to:

```
df['error'] = np.where((df['condition'] == 'B') & (df['count'].ge(3)),
                       df['Value'].rolling(3).sum().eq(0), np.nan)
df['error'] = np.where(df['condition'] == 'B',
                       df['error'].bfill(), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I still have to figure out if it works for my whole dataframe, but it looks ok